# How to compare floating point variables in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point

[This post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/124379) stated that you shouldn't compare floating point variables with `==` because of rounding errors. What should I use then, and when?

Answer (score 3):

You could use something along the lines of
`if (abs(result - expected) < 0.00001)`

or for a relative, rather than absolute, error:

```
float relativeError = abs((A - B) / B);
    if (relativeError <= maxRelativeError)
```

See this for more details.
http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: But beware.  That "relativeError"  calculation blows up if B is zero.  In general, if you use relative errors, zero will only ever compare "nearly equal" to a value which is exactly zero.